# Find the minimum of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{4yz+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2+yz+z^2}}{4zx+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+zx+x^2}}{4xy+1}$

Tags: inequality

Given $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=\frac{3}{2}.$
Find the minimum of
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{4yz+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2+yz+z^2}}{4zx+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+zx+x^2}}{4xy+1}$$

I think
$$\begin{aligned}
x^2+xy+y^2=&\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{3x^2}{4}-\frac{xy}{2}+\frac{3xy}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{3y^2}{4}\\=&\left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{xy}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{3x^2}{4}+\frac{3xy}{2}+\frac{3y^2}{4}\right)\\=&\frac{(x-y)^2}{4}+\frac{3(x+y)^2}{4}
\end{aligned}$$
Because $$(x-y)^2\geq 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{(x-y)^2}{4}\geq 0,$$ so $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{4yz+1} \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}(x+y)}{8yz+2}$$

Comment: my spelling  mistake

Answer (score 2):

You are in the right direction. Here is the next step

So, we have
$$S \ge \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left( \frac{x+y}{4yz+1}+\frac{y+z}{4zx+1}+\frac{z+x}{4xy+1}\right)$$

As $4yz \le (y+z)^2$, we deduce that
$$S \ge \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left( \frac{x+y}{(y+z)^2+1}+\frac{y+z}{(z+x)^3+1}+\frac{z+x}{(x+y)^2+1}\right)$$

Denote $a =x+y,b=y+z,c=z+x$, it suffices to find the mimimum of
$$L = \frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{b}{c^2+1}+\frac{c}{a^2+1}$$

Use the solution [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1820982p12162636) (attention, for your problem, we have $a+b+c=2(x+y+z)=3$, instead of $2$) (the key idea is to apply this inequality $\frac{a}{a^2+1} \ge 1-\frac{a}{2}$ for $a >0$), we have $L$ reaches its mimimum equal to $\frac{3}{2}$ iff $a=b=c = 1$

**Conclusion:**
$$S \ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $x = y= z = \frac{1}{2}$